# what is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in example2.php"

Tags: php, wordpress

im not really good with php but im trying to learn how crawler functions. im trying to apply what i learn about crawler in this site http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-basic-web-crawler-pull-information-website/

everything works great until i proceed on example2. i got this error

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in example2.php on line 7**

from this code

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = “localhost/wordpress”;
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find(‘a’) as $link){
echo $link->href.”<br/>”;
}
?>
```

i know this is a simple php but for a noob like me im not sure where should i look into. hope u can help. thank you

Comment: Uhh, what's with the funky double and single quotes? I recall I had that error when I accidently set my keyboard to Japanese, then all my quotes were actually multibyte characters, causing PHP to think the string didn't end.

Comment: Serious Question: Are you writing your code in MS Word or something?

Comment: ^ hahaha made my day, sorry for offtopic

Comment: yes i did copy it. but i didnt check the quotes cause i thought its fine. but thank you

Answer (score 4):

Here.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = 'localhost/wordpress';
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find('a') as $link){
    echo $link->href.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Seriously, improper quotes should be illegal on websites that show code.

Comment: and that's it. seriously thank you. i felt stupid already